# Prove that $\|f||_1 \leq \|f||_\infty$ if $f \in V$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V := C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to {\rm I\!R}$. I want to prove that if $f \in V$, then $\|f||_1 \leq  \|f||_\infty$
Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration is [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Basic_theorems_of_the_Lebesgue_integral): if $f\leq g$ on $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f(t)dt\leq  \int_a^b g(t)dt$.

Hence if $f$ is a bounded integrable function in $[a,b]$ then
$$\int_a^b|f(t)|dt\leq  \int_a^b\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|f(t)|dt=(b-a)\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|f(t)|.$$

Comment: How did you make this assumption?

Comment: Integration is a monotone operator $f\leq g$ on $[a,b]$ implies that $\int_a^b f(t)dt\leq  \int_a^b g(t)dt$.

Comment: How did you assume this $\int_a^b\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|f(t)|dt=(b-a)\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|f(t)|.$?

Comment: @Maddude $\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|f(t)|$ is a constant.

Answer (score 3):

You have $|f(x)|\leq sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|=M$ implies that $\int_0^1|f(x)|\leq \int_0^1M=(1-0)M=M$. This is equivalent to the result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $f\le g$ on $I$, then $\int_I f(x)dx \le \int_I g(x)dx$.
Also, $\forall x \in [0,1]$ $f(x)\le \|f\|_\infty$.